# Поиск определенных слов или их сочетания, а также слово-исключение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Хотел бы найти подстроки с таким шаблоном:

'DELETE' или 'FROM' или 'DELETE FROM', далее пробел, далее любое слово за которым не следует еще слово через точку, за исключением слова 'DUAL'

Что-то типа

```
'(DELETE|FROM|DELETE FROM) \w+', где \w+ != DUAL
но не
'(DELETE|FROM|DELETE FROM) \w+\.\w+'
```

Примеры фрагментов текста и желаемый результат например в c# Regex.Match

| фрагмент | желаемый результат |
| --- | --- |
| begin DELETE tbl1; | DELETE tbl1 |
| select FROM tbl2 | FROM tbl2 |
| ; DELETE FROM tbl3 where | DELETE FROM tbl3 |
| qqq DELETE DUAL; www |  |
| eee FROM DUAL rrr |  |
| ttt DELETE FROM DUAL where |  |
| yy DELETE sch1.tbl1; uuu |  |
| iii FROM sch2.tbl2 ooo |  |
| ppp DELETE FROM sch3.tbl3 aaa |  |

Comment: что-то типа этого? `(DELETE|FROM|DELETE FROM) (?!DUAL)\w+?(\n|$)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/d0Gglr/1 - для примера, прочитайте про группы негативного просмотра в regex,

Comment: Покажите конкретный пример текста, в котором нужно выполнить поиск паттерна.

Comment: Ваши решения завязываются на начало/конец строки, нельзя ли то же в любом месте текста? Уточню вопрос.

Comment: Это не решение, а гипотеза на кофейной гуще. :) Что было, и з того и слепил.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать

```cs
\b(?:DELETE(?:\s+FROM)?|FROM) \w+\b(?<!\b(?:DUAL|DELETE|FROM))(?!\.\w)
\b(?>DELETE(?:\s+FROM)?|FROM) \w+\b(?<!\bDUAL)(?!\.\w)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3EDELETE%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2BFROM%29%3F%7CFROM%29%20%5Cw%2B%5Cb%28%3F%3C!%5CbDUAL%29%28%3F!%5C.%5Cw%29&i=begin%20DELETE%20tbl1%3B%09DELETE%20tbl1%0D%0Aselect%20FROM%20tbl2%09FROM%20tbl2%0D%0A%3B%20DELETE%20FROM%20tbl3%20where%09DELETE%20FROM%20tbl3%0D%0Aqqq%20DELETE%20DUAL%3B%20www%09%0D%0Aeee%20FROM%20DUAL%20rrr%09%0D%0Attt%20DELETE%20FROM%20DUAL%20where%09%0D%0Ayy%20DELETE%20sch1.tbl1%3B%20uuu%09%0D%0Aiii%20FROM%20sch2.tbl2%20ooo%09%0D%0Appp%20DELETE%20FROM%20sch3.tbl3%20aaa). **Подробности**:

- `\b` - граница слова
- `(?:DELETE(?:\s+FROM)?|FROM)` - `DELETE` и необязательная последовательность из одного и более пробельных символов и `FROM` или просто `FROM`
- - пробел
- `\w+` - один и более букво-цифровых символов (и символов нижнего подчёркивания)
- `\b` - граница слова...
- `(?<!\b(?:DUAL|DELETE|FROM))` - сразу перед которой не может быть целого слова `DUAL`, `DELETE`, `FROM`
- `(?!\.\w)` - сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть точки + букво-цифрового символа (или символа нижнего подчёркивания).

Во втором случае шаблон сокращён за счёт атомарной группы, в которой невозможен поиск с возвратом ("бэктрекинг"), нет нужды проверять на совпадение `\w+` с `DELETE` и `FROM`.